# How do I define and use macros that define macros?

Tags: macros

I am new to TeX and LaTeX, and I am having trouble defining and using macros that define other macros.  I've read about how to do so (for example, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX#Plain_TeX_macros, as well as various previous questions here on this site), but I just haven't been able to get it to work.

Consider the following intentionally verbose snippet:

```
\def\apcodeEWR {EWR}
\def\apnameEWR {Newark Liberty International Airport}
\def\apcityEWR {Newark, NJ, USA}

\def\apcodeORY {ORY}
\def\apnameORY {Paris Orly Airport}
\def\apcityORY {Orly, France}

\def\apdescriptionEWR {\apnameEWR, located in \apcityEWR, has the airport code \apcodeEWR.}
\def\apdescriptionORY {\apnameORY, located in \apcityORY, has the airport code \apcodeORY.}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \apdescriptionEWR
    \item \apdescriptionORY
\end{itemize}
```

This outputs what I would expect:

```
* Newark Liberty International Airport, located in Newark, NJ, USA, has the airport code EWR.
* Paris Orly Airport, located in Orly, France, has the airport code ORY.
```

But I would like to instead do something like:

```
\apdefine{EWR}{Newark Liberty International Airport}{Newark, NJ, USA}
\apdefine{ORY}{Paris Orly Airport}{Paris, France}

\begin{itemize}
    \apdescribe{EWR}
    \apdescribe{ORY}
\end{itemize}
```

And I'd like to get past that hurdle first, but I feel I should just mention that ultimately, I'd really like to do something like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \foreachairport\apdescribe
\end{itemize}
```

So, now I'm trying to make that "apdefine" macro.  Based on the book that I linked to earlier, I'm trying this (having previously tried a bunch of other things):

```
\def\apdefine#1#2#3 {
    \expandafter\def\csnameapcode#1\endcsname {##1}
    \expandafter\def\csnameapname#1\endcsname {##2}
    \expandafter\def\csnameapcity#1\endcsname {##3}
}
```

That compiles without error.  But then I try to use it:

```
\apdefine{IBA}{Ibadan Airport}{Ibadan, Oyo, Nigeria}
```

I get nine errors, all on that line.  They are three groups of the following three:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...IBA}{Ibadan Airport}{Ibadan, Oyo, Nigeria}
Missing control sequence inserted. ...IBA}{Ibadan Airport}{Ibadan, Oyo, Nigeria}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \inaccessible. ...IBA}{Ibadan Airport}{Ibadan, Oyo, Nigeria}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I do it correctly? Or if there's a fundamentally different approach that can be used to do what I want, what's that? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It should be noted that your main mistake is that you need a space after `\csname`.  Your other problem is that the `##` in your `\def` would become a single `#`, so that your command would become `\def\apacodeEWR{#1}`.  The existing answers handle this problem (and nicely describe how you can achieve your ultimate goal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to `\apdefine` defines the three argument variables, as well as the description variable.  Then, it appends the airport code to a comma separated list named `\airportlist`.

After each airport is defined via `\apdefine`, one should invoke the `\readlist`, which will create a `listofitems` array named `\airports`, which can conveniently be used in a `\foreachitem` loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\ignoreemptyitems
\def\airportlist{}
\newcommand\apdefine[3]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname apcode#1\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname apname#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\def\csname apcity#1\endcsname{#3}%
  \expandafter\def\csname apdescription#1\endcsname{%
    #2, located in #3, has the airport code #1.}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\airportlist\expandafter{\airportlist#1,}
}
\apdefine{EWR}{Newark Liberty International Airport}{Newark, NJ, USA}
\apdefine{ORY}{Paris Orly Airport}{Paris, France}
\apdefine{IBA}{Ibadan Airport}{Ibadan, Oyo, Nigeria}
\readlist\airports{\airportlist}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \foreachitem\z\in\airports[]{\item \csname apdescription\z\endcsname}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `prop` lists of `expl3` to store the relevant data for each entry, and then store the key to each entry in a `seq` list. Defining a command, say, `\apdescribetext` which takes the text as argument, you can loop through the `seq` list and print the text.

`\apdefine` takes three arguments, the airport code, name, and address.
`\apdescribe` takes an airport code as argument and prints its info using `\apdescribetext`.
`\apdescribeall` loops through the list of airports and prints every one of them.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_vesterman_airports_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \apdefine { mmm }
  {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_vesterman_airports_seq {#1}
    \prop_new:c { g_vesterman_#1_prop }
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_vesterman_#1_prop } { name } {#2}
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_vesterman_#1_prop } { address } {#3}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \apdescribe { m }
  {
    \exp_args:Nff \apdescribetext
      { \prop_item:cn { g_vesterman_#1_prop } { name } }
      { \prop_item:cn { g_vesterman_#1_prop } { address } }
      {#1}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \apdescribeall { }
  { \seq_map_function:NN \g_vesterman_airports_seq \apdescribe }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\apdescribetext}[3]{\item #1, located in #2, has the airport code #3.}

\apdefine{EWR}{Newark Liberty International Airport}{Newark, NJ, USA}
\apdefine{ORY}{Paris Orly Airport}{Paris, France}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \apdescribeall
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```