# Define macros from a list processed by the listofitems package

Tags: automation, comma-separated-list, listofitems

I wanted to distinguish the control variables of different agents in a separate color so that my students can read examples more easily. To do so, I wanted to write a macro `\definevar{x,y;z}` that I could call at the beginning of each example to define `\var` before the semicolon as `{\color{player1} var}` and after the semicolon as `{\color{player2} var}`. I found [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498004/how-do-i-define-and-use-macros-that-define-macros) how to do it for a single variable, but was surprised that this method did not extend to lists processed by the `listofitems` package in a straightforward manner.

In below code, `\defvar` works well for a single variable, but somehow `\definevar` does not define the variables. If I replace `\foreach` with `pgfplot`'s `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, it defines the variables  but initializes them all to the last input variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, pgffor, listofitems}

\colorlet{player1}{blue}
\colorlet{player2}{red}

\newcommand{\defvar}[2]{
    \expandafter\def\csname #2\endcsname{{\color{player#1} #2}}
}

\newcommand{\definevar}[1]{
    \setsepchar{;/,}%
    \greadlist*\varlist{#1}%
    \foreach \pl in {1, ..., \varlistlen} {%
        \foreachitem \i \in \varlist[\pl] {%
            \defvar{\pl}{\i}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\defvar{1}{x}
\defvar{2}{y}
$\x + \y = 1$.

\definevar{x, y; z}
$\x + \y = \z$.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

1. `\defvar` needs to employ global `\gdef` rather than `\def`, since it is invoked inside of the loop groups of `\definevar`.
2. `\pl` and `\i` need to be once expanded before being used to call `\defvar`.  Without this, the `\defvar` retains the literal `\pl` and `\i` rather than using their replacement texts that you desire.

The MWE repaired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, pgffor, listofitems}

\colorlet{player1}{blue}
\colorlet{player2}{red}

\newcommand{\defvar}[2]{
    \expandafter\gdef\csname #2\endcsname{{\color{player#1} #2}}
}

\newcommand{\definevar}[1]{
    \setsepchar{;/,}%
    \greadlist*\varlist{#1}%
    \foreach \pl in {1, ..., \varlistlen} {%
        \foreachitem \i \in \varlist[\pl] {%
            \def\tmp{\expandafter\defvar\expandafter{\pl}}%
            \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\i}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\defvar{1}{x}
\defvar{2}{y}
$\x + \y = 1$.

\definevar{x, y; z}
$\x + \y = \z$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternate way to achieve those same goals is to use `\xdef` inside of `\defvar` instead of `\gdef` (as long as you `\noexpand` the `\color`).  That way, inside of `\definevar`, you can revert to the simpler syntax, without worrying about expansions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, pgffor, listofitems}

\colorlet{player1}{blue}
\colorlet{player2}{red}

\newcommand{\defvar}[2]{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #2\endcsname{{\noexpand\color{player#1} #2}}
}

\newcommand{\definevar}[1]{
    \setsepchar{;/,}%
    \greadlist*\varlist{#1}%
    \foreach \pl in {1, ..., \varlistlen} {%
        \foreachitem \i \in \varlist[\pl] {%
            \defvar{\pl}{\i}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\defvar{1}{x}
\defvar{2}{y}
$\x + \y = 1$.

\definevar{x, y; z}
$\x + \y = \z$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful. I think with this example I have finally understood when precisely to use `expandafter`.

Comment: @S.Olafsson The `\expandafter` ken comes suddenly, like a light bulb!  I know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expl3` so you don't need scratch macros.

The argument to `\definevar` is first split into pieces at semicolons, then each piece is examined to produce variables colored according to the piece number, you just need to define as many colors `player`*n* as you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{player1}{blue}
\colorlet{player2}{red}
\colorlet{player3}{green!60!blue}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { ##2 }
     {
      \cs_set_protected:cpn { ####1 } { \textcolor{player##1}{####1} }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\definevar{x;y}\x + \y = 1$.

$\definevar{x,y;z;t}\x+\y=\z-\t$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{player1}{blue}
\colorlet{player2}{red}
\colorlet{player3}{green!60!blue}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { ##2 }
     {
      \cs_set_protected:cx { __olafsson_var_####1: }
       {
        \exp_not:N \textcolor{player##1}{\mathchar\the\mathcode`####1}
       }
      \char_set_active_eq:Nc ####1 { __olafsson_var_####1: }
      \mathcode `####1 = "8000 \scan_stop:
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\definevar{x;y} x + y = 1$.

$\definevar{x,y;z;t} x + y = z - t$.

\end{document}
```

that yields the same output.

Comment: Nice, although the number of `#`  is quite scary... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano At each level you double them… `;-)`